# Node.js (http server): How to improve this local network server for simple file sharing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, localhost, local

The following code creates a simple local server that serves specified file to other devices on the same network from `192.168.0.x:8080`:

### The problems:

- Not sure how to stop the server once the file is downloaded on another device
- it throws an error if the specified file's name contains non-English characters: 
   `Uncaught TypeError: The header content contains invalid characters`
- download speed is under 25mb/s. Is it because of the method used?

I'm using Node.js HTTP module because I cannot use `express` module, because webpack throws this error when I `require('express')`:

```
./node_modules/http-errors/node_modules/statuses/index.js

Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, 
open 'C:\pathToProject\node_modules\http-errors\node_modules\statuses\index.js'
```

### Question:

Is there a better way to do it?

### Code:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const http = require('http')
const os = require('os')
const path = require('path')

startServer() {
  // GETTING NETWORK IP OF THE SERVER (ipv4, e.g. 192.168.0.x)
  var interfaces = os.networkInterfaces()
  var addresses = []
  for (var k in interfaces) {
      for (var k2 in interfaces[k]) {
          var address = interfaces[k][k2];
          if (address.family === 'IPv4' && !address.internal) {
              addresses.push(address.address)
          }
      }
  }
  var filtered = addresses.filter(x => x.includes("192.168.0"))

  // SERVING FILE FOR OTHER LOCAL DEVICES
  const hostname = filtered
  const port = 8080
  var fileName = "1.png"
  var filePath = path.join("C:/Users/u/Desktop", fileName)

  const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    var stat = fs.statSync(filePath);

    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=" + fileName
    });

    var readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
    // replacing all the event handlers with a simple call to readStream.pipe()
    readStream.pipe(res);

  })

  server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
   console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`)
  }) 
}
```